# What would be the best search method to conduct a literature review on anatomical variations?

Tags: publications, research-process, literature-review, literature-search, medicine

I'm currently conducting a literature review into anatomical variations of the portal vein. I'm using OVID and just wanted to check whether this is an efficient search strategy.

This is the Search Strategy:

> 1. Portal Vein*.mp.
> 2. Portal System*.mp.
> 3. 1 OR 2
> 4. Anatom*.mp.
> 5. variat* .mp
> 6. variant* .mp
> 7. 5 OR 6
> 8. 3 AND 4 AND 7

To break it down: I used 1 and 2 as a way to capture any mention of the Portal Vein (or more general mentions of the Portal System)
Then 4+5+6 are to capture any way that an anatomical variant could be mentioned, and 7 and 8 summate this.
(mp = mentioned anywhere)

Is this an efficient search strategy? I fear that I may accidentally be missing relevant articles using the search strategy, although the number of articles that has been turned up is quite high. Are there any unnecessary clauses?

Comment: Go to your local research librarian and work with them - they know more tricks of the trade than you could imagine.